# How to Create a clickable map

Tags: html, css, hover, maps

I'd like to take a map of california, chop it up into regions, and then allow the user to hover over those regions. When they click on the regions It would scroll them down the page to a specified point where they could read more info. How would I do this?

Comment: I am not so sure *you* can do it? Have *you* even tried to do it?

Comment: take an image of california, save it as multiple images in photoshop, piece it together using absolute positioning and go from there. You're going to have to try a few things before you post a question like this

Comment: Do we still use image maps anymore? Or are they outdated now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007431/location-country-clickable-maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever wondered using SVG based maps for this purpose?

A tool like [www.makeaclickablemap.com](http://www.makeaclickablemap.com) for example.

Answer (score 3):

Just create an image and apply a map on it, like this:

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="#sun" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="#mercur" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="#venus" alt="Venus">
  <area shape="poly" coords="48,311,105,248,96,210,75,205,38,234,8,310" href="#anything" title="Anything">
</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the map visualization you could use leaflet. For an example with map layers see: [Leaflet chloropleth example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html).